# how to handle situation where __construct() contains non existing property

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I have a one PHP class in which there is below constructor function :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->view_list = 'items';
    parent::__construct();
}
```

It gives the error like

> "The property view_list does not exist. Although not strictly required
>   by PHP, it is generally a best practice to declare properties
>   explicitly."

How can I handle this situation?

Thanks

Comment: You must declare the `view_list` variable in the class with a default value.

Comment: `public $view_list = 'items';`

Comment: Well, you don't need to give it a value. You just need to initialize the variable. `public $view_list;`/`private $view_list;` would be sufficient

Comment: No but as its hardcoded value you might as well, then it saves a line in the construct.

Comment: True point, Lawrence. I guess my comment was more aimed at @user2342558's comment

Comment: I inserted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the *notice* message because your class does not have a property called `$view_list`. PHP can handle this, but like the message indicates, it is considered best practice to create these beforehand. This makes the code easier to read. You can also set a default value for the variable, if you do not provide any variable value in the constructor.

```
class YourClassName extends SomeClass {

    private $view_list;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->view_list = 'items';
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Or, setting the variable outside the constructor method, if the value is always the same:

```
class YourClassName extends SomeClass {

    private $view_list = 'items';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```